# Using DropDown Menu Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to MVC Core , and I wanted to do an example of DropDown List coming from the Database using ViewModel.

my example is :

Table ( Car ): with CarId,CarName,CarBrand. [FK(ColorId), FK(UserID)]
Table ( Color ): with ColorId , Color

```
 public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CarBrand { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CarName { get; set; }


    //--------Foreign[ColorID]--------Foreign[UserId]--------------------------------
    // Foreign key to customer
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }    // Dropdown List 

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }   // Logged in UserId

}

    public class Color
{
    [Key]
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
}
```

in the database save few colors : 1=Red , 2=Yellow, 3=Green

and this my View

```
@model DropDownListOtherModel.Models.Car
<div ">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="Car-form" method="Post" asp-controller="Car" asp-action="Save">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @*<label asp-for="FullName"></label>*@
                <input asp-for="CarBrand" placeholder=" Car Brand" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CarBrand" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @*<label asp-for="FullName"></label>*@
                <input asp-for="CarName" placeholder=" Car Name" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CarName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cars">Choose a Color:</label>
                <br />
                <select name="cars" id="cars" asp-for="Color">
                    <option value="1">RED</option>
                    <option value="2">YELLOW</option>
                    <option value="3">GREEN</option>
                    <option value="4">BLACK</option>
                    <option value="5">WHITE</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">submist</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my View I should be showing the Form with 2 input CarName , CarBrand, and 3 Dropdown color, and when I save , it should be attached with the form.

First how should I display color in Select list,
second, should I update the Save method, to include colorID ?

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way,

***Model:***

```
  public class CarColorViewModel
    {
        
        public String CarName { get; set; }
        public List<Color> colors { get; set; }
    }
```

***Controller:***

```
 public IActionResult LoadDropDownFromDatabase()
        {
         // Get your database value here, then bind to list I am  binding here a seed value.
            var color = new List<Color>()
            {
                new Color(){ ColorName = "Select Color",ColorId =1},
                new Color(){ ColorName = "Red",ColorId =2},
                new Color(){ ColorName = "Blue",ColorId =3},
                new Color(){ ColorName = "Green",ColorId =4}

            };
            var model = new CarColorViewModel();
            model.colors = color;


            return View(model);
        }
```

***View:***

```
@model CarColorViewModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = " "; }

<h2>Load DropDown From Backend</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("LoadDropDownFromDatabase", "StackOverFlow"))
{
   
  
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr><th>Car Name </th><td > @Html.TextBoxFor(r => Model.CarName, new { @class = "form-control" })</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Select Color</th><td> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.colors, new SelectList(Model.colors, "ColorId", "ColorName"), new { @class = "form-control" })</tr>
    </table>
  
   
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

***Output:***

[image]

Hope this would help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: thanks for trying .. but I keep getting null reference error

Comment: Did you able to debug it where its getting null reference error? Firstly just copy and paste my solution then run and then you can modify. If you just copy and paste it definately should work. Let me know the update.

Comment: I did debug, and definitely I've changed the necessary changes,  but it keep throwing the Null Reference,  I'm now working on it,  I will update u

Comment: After playing with it,  I brought the color from the database, then added them to the List, then displayed them, sorry it took me a little while, but I'm still new this.

Comment: No worries , feel free to share once encounter any problem on this.

Answer (score 0):

add ColorId to a Car class

```
 public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CarBrand { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CarName { get; set; }

    public int ColorId { get; set; }  
   [ForeignKey(nameof(ColorId))]
    [InverseProperty("Cars")]
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }    

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }   // Logged in UserId

}

  public class Color
{
    [Key]
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ColorName { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty(nameof(Car.Color))]
   public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars{ get; set; }    

}
```

remove id and name from select

```
<select  asp-for="ColorId">
 <option value="0">Select Color</option>
 <option value="1">RED</option>
  <option value="2">YELLOW</option>
   <option value="3">GREEN</option>
    <option value="4">BLACK</option>
   <option value="5">WHITE</option>
</select>
```

action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Car car)
{
....your code
}
```